# Why can my Scanner classes compile, but not execute? (Java)

Tags: java, compilation, execute, bluej

I'm using BlueJ. I have a program that uses the Scanner without any issues in the same project. I have another program that compiles, but does not execute. On the BlueJ project screen it shows "Work indicator: indicates when virtual machine is executing".

Here is my code which I don't think is incorrect.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testing
   {
       public static void main( String[] args)
          {
              Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
              double radius = scan.nextDouble();
              double circumference = (2*Math.PI*radius);
              double area = (Math.PI*radius*radius);
              System.out.println(circumference);
              System.out.println(area);
            }
}
```

I've tried changing the name of the scanner( ex. scan ) to that of the class that works, and it didn't fix it. I'm not getting any errors at all.

I also made a new class where you simply input something into the Scanner and it prints it out onto the screen, and it doesn't work either. Help?

**EDIT:** I just needed to add `System.out.println( "Enter Radius: " );` before the `scan.nextDouble()` for the terminal window to pop up. Thank you.

Comment: Are you typing in a double and hitting enter once you run your program?

Comment: your program is waiting for your input. Add `System.out.print("Enter radius:");` just after the `Scanner` declaration

Comment: @Takendarkk The terminal windows wouldn't even pop up.

Comment: @George If your problem is solved then you may either add your own answer or better discard this post as it doesn't help any future reader. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add `System.out.println( "Enter Radius: " );` before the `scan.nextDouble()` for the terminal window to pop up. Thanks everyone.